# Angular strap custom delay

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying out the new [AngularStrap v2](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##tooltips). Is there a nicer way to delay the tooltip. I don't want the user to always see the tooltip, just when he/she hovers longer than 2 seconds above something. With the attribute "delay", it always shows. That can get annoying though after a while.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-trigger="hover" data-delay="1000" type="button" title="Edit" data-placement="left" bs-tooltip="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##tooltips), use option:

```
delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
```

You can also override default for all tooltips:

```
angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs')

.config(function($tooltipProvider) {
  angular.extend($tooltipProvider.defaults, {
    html: true,
    delay: { show: 5000, hide: 4000 }
  });
})
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m5cImE27UoLSDPKJMCxS?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thx for the answer. It doesn't exactly do what I had in mind. I want the tooltip only to show if the mouse hovers at least 2 seconds over the object. If not the tooltip never opens...

Comment: You can use [commas](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/commit/1568231fd24a55b12d0d689628681264a661c583) to set the delay, e.g. `data-delay="5000,4000"`

Answer (score 0):

This way will work:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-trigger="hover" data-delay="5000,4000" type="button" title="Edit" data-placement="left" bs-tooltip="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
```

You will have to use data-delay="5000,4000" in the template